# How to render two level elements dynamically based on some conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

suppose **svg** is the parent element and **rect** will be the child element in the final rendering.
i want to render it on different changing states

for every 5 **rects** there will be a single **svg** parent,so if **rect** value is 8 ,it would render it as first **svg** with 5 child elements and second **svg** with remaining 3 elements

```
const Svg = ({total}) => {
 let rects = total
 let totalSvgs = Math.ceil(rects/5)
return(
// i have tried using map and for-loops here
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary** Divide your `Rects` into an array of `rectChunks` ... which would make `map` straight forward...

```
const rects = []; /** your rect objs */
const svgs = []; /** your svg objs */

const chunkSize = 5;
const rectLength = rects.length;

const svgLength = Math.ceil(rectLength / chunkSize);

/** 1. Divide your array of rects into an array of small chunks of size 5 */
const rectChunks = [];

for (let i = 0; i < rectLength; i += chunkSize) {
  const chunk = rects.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
  rectChunks.push(chunk);
}

/** 2. Render */
return svgs.map((svgItem, index) => (
  <Svg {...svgItem}>
    {rectChunks[index].map(rectItem => (
      <Rect {...rectItem} />
    ))}
  </Svg>
));
```